# How do I fire multiple javascript events on a webpage using python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am webscraping Glassdoor.com for company reviews using Python.

Currently, I am using Beautiful Soup and grequests. This is working fine for all the fields I need, except for the "Advice to Management" section which only loads in once the `Continue Reading` button is pressed. See below an example below for [this page of reviews](https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Alteryx-Reviews-E351220.htm):

[continue reading button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2jbH.png)
[expanded review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3FWh.png)

There are no changes to the URL as far as I can tell, but there is a JS click-event being fired in the console:
`Event: EiReviews: Click [continueReading-71858088]`

I found a tutorial online for `selenium webdriver` such as [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-click-on-a-button-with-javascript-executor-in-selenium-with-python), and I wrote this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Alteryx-Reviews-E351220.htm")

btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__continueReading").click()
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].click();",btn)
```

I need something that scales better, as this takes ~20sec to open chrome and click on a singular button. I need to be able to click on every "Continue Reading" button on the page as my end goal is to scrape every review for ~1,000 companies.

Comment: By looking at the HTML of the page, you can notice that right before the `<div id="Container">` object, there is a `script` object starting with `window.appCache={....` which contains the complete reviews but in a sort of a strange dictionary/json format, for example it contains the text which appears when you click on Continue Reading `"summary":"Great place to work, been here 4+ years","summaryOriginal":null,"advice":"Don't rush too finish a project"`. Maybe you can extract everything from there

Comment: Alternatively, you can load the site with selenium, loop through all the reviews and automatically click the Continue Reading button if present

Comment: Thanks! The `window.appCache` `dict` has all the information I need.

Comment: Good! Is it ok if I post the comment with the solution as an answer so that you can then accept it and the question is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the HTML of the page, you can notice that right before the `<div id="Container">` object, there is a script object starting with `window.appCache={....` which contains the complete reviews in a dictionary format, for example it contains the text which appears when you click on Continue Reading

```
"summary":"Great place to work, been here 4+ years",
"summaryOriginal":null,"advice":"Don't rush too finish a project"
```